# No listview groups shown on vb.net-console-application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, console-application

I have programmed a vb.net-DLL which contains a form with a listview-control. In this listview I want to show items in the view 'details'. In these view I can display the items in groups.

I integrate these DLL in my winform-application and all works. The form is loaded and the items are shown in the listview-control in the groups.

Now, I have a second application which is a console-application. I also open the form during the runtime. The items are shown, but without the groups. Whats going worng?

PS: Both applications run on the same pc.

screenshot winforms-app: (ok)
[image]

screenshot console-app:  (not ok)
[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like your console version is running `Application.EnableVisualStyles()`

Comment: how can I switch they on? ...ahh ok ...System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles()      I will try!

Comment: Show the relevant code that runs your WinForms.

Comment: WinForms needs an STAThread attribute and `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` call.  Doesn't even sound like you are calling `Application.Run(...)` either.  Like I said, you have to show your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have to call the System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles() function e.g. at the constructor of the form-control. Thanks to @LarsTech